# Unity Holotoolkit Spriterender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to add airtap handlers to gameobject with SpriteRender component but it's didn't work. The code applying to the gameobject with meshRender component work well. Could someone help?

Comment: Please add more detail including code samples. As is, this question doesn't include enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: Rather than adding airtap to a SpriteRenderer, use a UI Image + UI Button components. Those are already set up to work on the HoloLens.